# Was Ruth beautiful?

Tags: historical-figures, book-of-ruth, beauty

The Tanach seems to make a big deal out of the beauty of certain women, including Sarah, Rebecca, Rachel, and Esther, but no mention of is made regarding Ruth's appearance. This seems particularly odd in a "love story" of sorts. Was Ruth beautiful, and why is that detail relevant to other narratives but not to this one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/michlol/ruth2.htm:

> נדמה לנו כי אנו מכירים את רות היכרות קרובה. אבל כשאנו מנסים להעלות את דמותה בדמיוננו, מתברר לנו כמה מעט אנו יודעים עליה. האם יפה הייתה? אלשיך טוען כי משכה את עיני הסובבים אותה בזכות יופייה, עד כי הנער אשר על הקוצרים דאג להזכיר לבועז כי מואביה היא, לבל יתפתה אחריה. אבן עזרא (ג,י) טוען כי אנשי בית לחם אהבוה בגלל יופיה. כל הציירים מציירים אותה כאישה יפה. אבל כלל לא ברור שיפה הייתה: מעט נשים יפות מוזכרות במקרא: שרה, ורחל, תמר אבישג ואסתר ובנות איוב. רות אינה אחת מהן. רות ניכרת בנוכחותה, יותר מאשר במראיה. כאשר היא נמצאת - הכל סובב סביבה, גם אם אין היא פוצה פה ומדברת.‏

The question is whether Rus was beautiful. The Alshich and ibn Ezra say she was at least to the people around her. But that may not mean she was an all time beauty.

Answer (score 4):

If one refers to the Midrash in [Rus Rabbah 4:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth_Rabbah.4.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it notes that Rus was aged 40 when she went out to the field (of Boaz) and her beauty made an impression on all those around her.

> רַבִּי יַנַּאי אָמַר בַּת אַרְבָּעִים שָׁנָה הָיְתָה...(רות ב, ג): וַיִּקֶר מִקְרֶהָ, אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן כָּל הָרוֹאֶה אוֹתָהּ מֵרִיק קֶרִי
>
> Rav Yannai says that she was 40 years old...'And she happened by chance' ([Rus 2:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth.2.3?lang=bi)) - (is understood to mean as follows...) Rabbi Yochanan says - all who saw her experienced a seminal emission.

The [Mishnas Rebbi Eliezer](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnat_DeRabbi_Eliezer_on_Ruth_Rabbah.4.4.1?lang=en) qualifies this that it was as a result of her beauty.

Indeed, in the above cited verse (2:3), the [Torah Temimah](https://www.sefaria.org/Torah_Temimah_on_Ruth.2.3.3?lang=en) brings this Midrash and explains this effect of her causing others to be "מֵרִיק קֶרִי" in the footnote there and writes:

> דריש ע"ד מ"ש (תענית ה' ב') כל האומר רחב רחב מיד נקרי, **וזה לסבת יפיה הנפרז, וכן הכא**
>
> One can expound similarly on that which is written (in [Taanis 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.5b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - "Anyone who says 'Rachav Rachav'  immediately experiences a seminal emission" (due to the arousal of desire caused by Rachav’s great beauty) **and the reason is to emphasise her beauty, and so it is here (with Rus).**

So it would seem from these sources that she was indeed a beautiful woman.

Comment: Let’s be honest every human being is beautifull in it’s own way, it’s all the work of the Creator. In most cases where beauty is emphasized, the beauty plays an important part in the narration.